# How can I programmatically rename fields, parameters, class names, and method names in .Java files?

Tags: java, refactoring, rename

Is there any library that could do this for me? And as example if I rename a method I need to rename all use cases of it too.

```
public void c() -> start() {
        //...
    }

public void test() {
        Something something = new Something();
        something.field1.c() -> start();
    }
```

This should not only be for methods it should be for everything that is being renamed (Fields, Params...)

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that I need to rename 25,000+ fields, methods, etc. 
And that would be really time consuming if you rename it in an IDE

Comment: You have some mapping already that maps original name to modified name?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it just gives me the new name and there are some methods that have the same name and to find the right one I need the method's parameters and the return value, and that's really hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for AST.
There are very few tutorials about it, maybe you can refer to the link below.

[EclipseJDT](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) and [AST](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. Thank you so much!